# cordova_not_availale error on device when running with livereload

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I have an old ionic 3 app that was working well a year ago. I am not upgrading it to ionic4/5. I would like to compile it and make a few changes. But I am getting the following error when I run it on a device

**ionic cordova run android -lsc --device**

> console.warn: Ionic Native: tried calling BackgroundMode.on, but
> Cordova is not available. Make sure to a)
> run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html

But the app opens in the device (so it is detecting the real device) and shows errors when it looks for cordova.

> Runtime error: cordova_not_available

But the app works as it should when I run it without the livereload option as follows-

**ionic cordova run android --device**

This is the project ionic info -

cli packages: (/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-sim : 6.1.3 
Node    : v9.5.0
npm     : 5.7.0 
OS      : macOS High Sierra
Xcode   : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with this work around given here - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-not-available-with-livereload-on-real-device/126409/4

Edit file node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/dev-server/serve-config.js and change last line to:

```
 exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app/src/main', 'assets', 'www');
```